# When I use pm2 deploy the project to my Ubuntu,from Mac is ok,from windows bash,it won't work

Tags: deployment, pm2

```
pm2 deploy ecosystem.json production
```

**In my MAC,everything is ok,But in windows,when I use Cmder,it goes like:**

```
/bin/bash: 

C:/Users/travins/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pm2-deploy/deploy: No such file or directory
Deploy failed
```

**When I use git bash:**

```
connect EPERM //./pipe/rpc.sock
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=C:\Users\travins\.pm2
events.js:183
```

Comment: PS: I had install pm2 global use "npm install pm2 -g"